# How to handle sprites more than 200 with SpriteList of Playstation Mobile SDK?

Tags: 2d, sprite, bullet, playstation

I am working on 2D shooter game which includes hundreds of bullets and implemented a simple test based on PlayStation mobile SDK tutorial, and slowing down of the frame rate is my main problem.

Scene is scheduled to generate bullet object inherited from SpriteUV, and every generated object is added to SpriteList like below, and the result was that bullets more than 200 showed 55~60 fps. Below are links to my question and codes which I uploaded to the community.

- http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/GameEngine2D/SpriteList-SpriteUV-and-bullet-sprites-more-than-200/td-p/16539301

Is it normal to show slow-down of frame rate with 200 bullets, or am I doing totally wrong way of handling SpriteUV and SpriteList? If it isn't wrong, how can I handle sprites more than 200? (about 300~500)

- Bullet_01.png: 8 by 8 pixel, 2.8 kb (Is it too big?)
- Tutorial used for study: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/06/04/PlayStation-Studio-SDK-Tutorial-Using-SpriteLists.aspx%29